# HTML Formatting tossing #error

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am attempting to format an expression in SSRS with an HTML code and am getting *#Error* tossed upon report preview. My expression looks as follows:

```
="<b>Region: </b>" + Fields!RegionID.Value
```

I have also ensured that **HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles** has been selected under **Placeholder Properties**. Has anyone experienced this behavior before?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just looking to get part of a text string displayed in bold or does it have to be HTML-based?

Comment: I'm looking to get part of the text displayed in bold. Do you know another method?

Comment: Yes, please see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSRS 2008 and above, you can use placeholders to achieve this.

See [Formatting Text and Placeholders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207048.aspx) for more details.

To give a quick example, in a textbox, enter some text then right click on the empty space to the right of the text:

[image]

You can set the placeholder properties to display your required field in the Value property:

[image]

You now have two distinct text parts in the textbox that can be formatted independently, e.g. one bold and one normal:

[image]